# Sending _method paramater through ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, post, serialization

I have an ajax form that I need to serialize. I also need to set the _method of the data form manually. Here is my current implementation.

```
 $.ajax({
            url: http://someposturl.com/object,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                _method: method
            },
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function(json) {
               alert("YAY");
            },
            error: function(json){
               alert("BOO!"):
            }
        });
```

Unfortunately, as I'm doing it above, the data variable is being overwritten.

How would I write this so that the data contains both the _method and the serialized form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
var data = $('form').serialize() + "&_method=" + method;  

$.ajax({
        url: http://someposturl.com/object,
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        success: function(json) {
           alert("YAY");
        },
        error: function(json){
           alert("BOO!"):
        }
    });
```

Comment: A variation of this did it!

data = $('form').serialize()
data['_method'] = "POST"